# Sanctum authentication with roles

Tags: laravel, authentication, roles, laravel-sanctum

I'm trying to implement Sanctum SPA authentication with roles (user/admin). The thing is that I want to use separate admin table.
Read all of the laravel documentation related to that subject but with no result.
Tried to make a new guard and provider inside of **config/auth.php** but didn't succeed at conjunction it with Sanctum.
Any additional resources and ides how to do it will be appreciated! :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Sanctum (SPA auth) only deals with authentication (who you are) - what you are asking/looking for is how to authorize users (what you can do) to perform/access specific resources.

If what you need is only to separate users between regular users and admins, you can get away with a boolean column on the `users` table: `is_admin` and then use that to check wether a user is an admin or not.

If you need more granular control, you could probably make use of Spatie's [laravel-permissions](https://docs.spatie.be/laravel-permission/v3/introduction/) package.